# Serialize a "Dog" as if it was an "Animal" using Gson

Tags: json, subclass, gson

I have a **concrete** base class, `Animal`, and several subclasses `Dog`, `Cat` and so on.

The details of `Dog` and `Cat` are irrelevant, so I would like to serialize instances of these subclasses the same way as `Animal`s are serialized.

There are quite a few such subclasses so I would prefer a solution that doesn't list them all. Something based on an `instanceof Animal` would be ideal.

Comment: Whats the context? Are you trying to serialize these subclasses as their parent class in all cases? Or are you determining at run time when and where you want to ignore the subclass type and just serialize as the parent class?

Comment: Same in all cases. ("compile time decision")

Comment: I know of no way that this can be done in all cases via compile time decision. [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) can do it via its `@JsonSerialize(as)` annotation, but there is no equivalent (that I know of) in Gson. The best you can do is register a type heirarchy adapter via a GsonBuilder, to override the serialization behavior for the parent class. This will on a parser-by-parser basis.

Comment: If you never want to serialize them except as the parent, you would mark all fields in the subclasses as `transient`. If there's cases where you do, you could use the `@Expose` annotation in the parent and use `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

(Moved from comment to full answer)

If you *never* want to serialize the subclasses as those subsclasses and only as the parent, simply mark all fields in the subclasses as `transient` - by default `Gson` won't serialize them.

If you want to be able to do it either way, mark all fields in the parent class with the Gson `@Expose` annotation. Then when you serialize you can choose which way to serialize by using:

```
Gson gson = GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

When you only want the parent class represented in the JSON.

Comment: This seems like a "one-shot" solution. I do have a typeHierarchyAdapter though. (`Animal` isn't my root class in this hierarchy.) I bet instances of `Dog` will have a `type="Dog"` field in the serialization. This will not be understood by the deserializing end. I'll give this a try nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, that makes it more complicated. You can go further with defining your own `ExclusionStrategy` and using your own custom annotations. http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html - either way it's prob a bit of work.

Comment: Good point. Right now I'm considering listing all subclasses explicitly, and let them all share a JsonSerializer that treats them as an `Animal`. :-/

Answer (score 0):

My naive hack, that I coded just for fun (but that worth a try if performances are not a problem).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Animal> al = new ArrayList<Animal>();
  al.add(new Dog());
  al.add(new Fish());
  al.add(new Dog());

  String originalString = new Gson().toJson(al);
  System.out.println(originalString);

  ArrayList<Animal> a = new ArrayList<Animal>();
  Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Animal>>() {}.getType();

  a = new Gson().fromJson(originalString, listType);

  String newString = new Gson().toJson(a);

  System.out.println(newString);

}
```

Result:

```
Original string: [{"feet":4,"name":"Dog"},{"canSwim":true,"name":"fish"},{"feet":4,"name":"Dog"}]
New string: [{"name":"Dog"},{"name":"fish"},{"name":"Dog"}]
```